# Custom formatter cucumberjs

Tags: junit, cucumberjs

I've been searching for a way to get cucumberjs report to output junit xml. I know that there's a bunch of npm modules that does this. However, they are NOT doing it how I want them to. They are splitting up each step as test case, but I would like for each test case to be a scenario instead. 
I did find [this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/pull/100); but as I continue reading this post I am not sure if this feature was added to cucumberjs it self or not. Then somewhere someone wrote that cucumberjs did allow for custom formatters. I went to read the documentation on this [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/custom_formatters.md). 
I also looked at the example but the example was how to run a test on the custom formatter not how to add/use a custom formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Couple month ago I stuck with same problem. To cut long story short I decide that I didn't found any appropriate solution, so I wrote own formatter. You just can install `cucumber-junit-formatter` from npm. As I understand from your question this formatter will covers you needs.